# Api in php to open Firefox in server

Tags: php, api

I have made an API in which when a user hit the API , a Firefox should run on server. I have written a shell script and executed it in php using exec command.I am using php from lampp .I am getting error that Firefox profile is missing or inaccessible.please help
**apicall.php**

```
<?php
$request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if($request_method==='GET')
{
    exec('bash test.sh 2>&1',$output);
    print_r(json_encode($output));
}

?>
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash/
export DISPLAY=:0
firefox
```

Comment: Please, show us your code, so we could help you.

Comment: Did you open Firefox for yourself at least once? To me it appears, that the profile configuration file may not be created. See [How to run Firefox when your profile is missing or inaccessible](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-run-firefox-when-profile-missing-inaccessible)

Comment: You could try [bypassing Firefox' Profile Manager](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Bypassing_the_Profile_Manager) in order to start it with a custom hard-coded profile that you can save along your api source code.

Comment: <?php
$request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if($request_method==='GET')
{
 exec('bash test.sh 2>&1',$output);
 print_r(json_encode($output));
}

?>
above is code for apicall.php (url in which api is hit)

Comment: #!/bin/bash/
export DISPLAY=:0
firefox            code for tesh.sh

Comment: Please put the code **as text** and **inside the question**. Code in pictures and in comments is unreadable.

Comment: i have added code .please look at it. @Federico

Comment: Consider that you're probably running this as the `www` user. Since firefox tries to create its profile inside the home directory, you should check whether that user has a home directory defined and accessible.

Comment: How to check that ? Can you elaborate @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: @RishavKumar see Anuga's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Apache2/PHP is being run by user: `www-data`.

The script is therefore run by `www-data`.

Firefox is being executed by `www-data`.

`www-data` has `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` as default `home directory` and it's probably just read only.

For more information about getting and setting Firefox's profile path:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/239543/get-the-default-firefox-profile-directory-from-bash

Comment: I am using lampp.So,i dont have any path /var/www . So,how to fix it.I run apache by using sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Comment: What user is running lampp?

Comment: I think www-data is running but i am not sure.How to check it ? @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: `ps aux|grep lampp`. First column of the result is the user running the process.

Comment: daemon and rishav is running 
@FedericoklezCulloca